# What is the difference between "in conclusion" and "by way of conclusion"?

Tags: phrases

"In conclusion" is common, while "by way of conclusion" is quite formal. But what does "by way of conclusion" truly mean that differs from "in conclusion"?

Comment: How did you determine that *by way of conclusion* is quite formal?

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us examples of complete sentences rather than fragments.

Comment: **By way of conclusion is **verbal** or spoken. I would never use it in a written text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you consider other situations where "by way of" might typically be used -- for instance

> By way of food, there was nothing in the fridge except a long-abandoned can of mouldy beans and a blackened banana
>
> By way of reading material, the owner of the yacht had furnished himself with all 233 of Jeffrey Archer's finest novels

-- the expression seems to mean pretty much the same thing as "in terms of". Accordingly, *by way of conclusion* means roughly *in terms of (a) conclusion*, which in turn doesn't seem very different from *in conclusion*.

Comment: I think *serving as* is a better replacement. *By way of* is often used when whether the offering meets the requirements or not is debatable; your first example fits nicely here.

Answer (score 1):

To my (American) ear, "by way of conclusion" means: "This is what I am offering as a conclusion". It may imply that this is not a real conclusion (in the technical sense of "given the arguments I have cited, I conclude that…). It may not be a "conclusion" at all, e.g. "By way of conclusion, let me mention a funny story I came across recently…".

When I as a reader encounter the phrase "in conclusion", I have every right to expect that the author will present a conclusion to, or at least a summing up of, the arguments and ideas they have presented in the article.

Answer (score 0):

I was just wondering this very question myself!  I think that "By way of conclusion, I will summarize my main arguments" means "*As* my conclusion I will summarize my main arguments."

But "In conclusion, I will summarize my main arguments" means, "Here is how I will conclude: by summarizing my main arguments."

The difference is subtle, but I think the first but not the second suggests that there are other good ways (perhaps better ones) of concluding than by giving a summary, and instead of concluding by doing one of *those*, I will conclude by giving a summary of my main arguments.  But the second one just says, *This is what I'm going to do*:

My real question, though, was how this meaning could be derived from the more general meaning of "By way of...."

Comment: The author who writes "by way of conclusion" is probably not concerned with the subtleties of language.

Comment: @TimRomano Can you say more?